# How do I get my Canon Pixma IP1500 to work with 12.04?

Tags: printing, canon

How do I get my Canon Pixma IP1500 to work with 12.04?

I have tried many things and Ubuntu says it is installed and working. The printer works in Windows so I know it is functioning, I just would rather use Ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-pixmaip1500series
```

[The source](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-printer-driver-canon-pixma-ip-series-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got my Canon MP180 to work (it should be similar)

1. Go to this webpage: `http://localhost:631/admin` (Copy/paste, can't link to `localhost`)
2. Click the 'Add Printer' button
3. Type your Ubuntu username and password
4. Choose your printer from the list, click 'Continue'
5. Fill in the fields with information, click 'Continue'
6. Choose the model of your printer from the list, click 'Continue'
7. Choose default printing options, click 'Set Default Options'
8. Done

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I had trouble with my Pixma too, and those `michael-gruz` drivers didn't fully resolve the problems.

**I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04** and suddenly everything works *without specific drivers* -  - even the scanner is now detected! So I would recommend that you upgrade, even if that means leaving LTS behind. In your situation, I am guessing that LTS is less important than being able to print (and scan?) at all.